# What is best practice for using decorators in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solid-principles

In my rails app there is a reporting page with a lot of stats and a lot of charts, there are over 40 values and over 12 charts to give an idea.

There is a lot of data to manipulate so I started moving that code out to decorators, but I'm not sure this is the best way as my controller now looks like shit.

I'm having trouble tracking code - what has been tested, what is working, what is redundant, so maintability already sucks a bit.

Can anyone offer advice or suggest a pragmatic solution/methodology for keeping my project from turning into an absolute mess? Is there something I'm doing fundamentally wrong regarding my method or process, or a gap in my knowledge of Ruby/Rails that can be discerned from my example code below and should be done in another way?

Here's an example of my base decorator class, a decorator and my controller:

Base decorator:

```
module Insights
  class InsightDecorator
    attr_reader :insight

    def initialize(insight)
      @insight = insight
    end

    def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
      insight.send(method_name, *args, &block)
    end

    def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
      insight.respond_to?(method_name, include_private) || super
    end
  end
end
```

One of 14 decorators:

```
module Insights
  class FanAdds < InsightDecorator
    def previous
      FanAdds.new(Insight.previous page_id, insight_end)
    end

    def get_likes_increase
      previous.insight.is_a?(Insight) ? (get_monthly_total - previous.get_monthly_total).to_i : 0
    end

    def get_daily_total
      begin
        get_insight_by_title('Daily New Likes')['values']
      rescue
        logger.error 'No daily new likes found'
        nil
      end
    end

    def get_monthly_total
      get_daily_adds.inject(0) {|total, fan| total + fan['value'] }
    end
  end
end
```

Show method in insight contoller (is looking way bad! Is there a better way to fix this?!?)

```
def show
  @insight_page_impressions_gender = Insights::PageImpressionsGender.new(@insight)
  @insight_page_monthly            = Insights::PageMonthly.new(@insight)
  @insight_page_stories            = Insights::PageStories.new(@insight)
  @insight_engagement_day_of_week  = Insights::EngagementDayOfWeek.new(@insight)    
  @insight_charts_fan_growth       = Insights::Charts::FanGrowth.new(@insight)
  @insight_charts_impressions      = Insights::Charts::PageImpressions.new(@insight)
  @paid_organic_viral_impressions  = Insights::Charts::PaidOrganicViralImpressions.new(@insight)
  @story_type                      = Insights::Charts::StoryTypesOfImpressions.new(@insight)
  @age_gender_impressions          = Insights::Charts::AgeGenderOfImpressions.new(@insight)
  @insight_charts_stories          = Insights::Charts::Stories.new(@insight)
  # ... and so on
  @fan_adds                        = Insights::FanAdds.new(@insight)
end
```

Comment: I'd look to create a factory that returns the requested insight, and use that in the controller.

Comment: This is a great question! I would suggest however that it might be better suited for a discussion on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com rather than StackOverflow as there isn't necessarily a single, definitive answer to your question. I encourage you to repost it and share the link.